# How do I use ui themes for jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datatables, themeroller, jquery-ui-theme

I've been trying to add the "smoothness" theme to my jquery datatable with no success.
My datatable just doesn't get styled.

Here is my header code:

```
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
    @import "/DataTables/media/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css"
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables/media/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#join').dataTable( {
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
            } );
    } );    
</script>
```

And here is the form at the body:

```
<table id="join" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="80%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here??

Thanks for any help.

Comment: are you getting any console errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import `jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css` file so it will work with the themes.  Or if you aren't using themes then just use the `jquery.dataTables.css`

You should also try importing your css like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables/media/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css"/>
```

Or if you want to keep the import statements - You were missing the `url` part

```
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
   @import url("DataTables/media/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css");
   @import url("DataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css");
</style>
```

So in the end your css was not getting imported therefore your table had no formatting applied

Comment: I added `@import "/DataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css"` but it remains unstyled. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you have the files in those locations?  What browser are you using?  Check the console for any errors

Comment: @akrabi I just updated my answer also.  Try importing your style sheets like that

Comment: that did the trick! can't believe that was the problem.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I completely understand the purpose of each of the included .js files. What functionality does each one of them add?

Comment: they are the css files actually.  In your import statement you were just missing the `url' part i think.  I'll update my answer for you

Comment: Oh, now i see...
But what functionality does each one of these add?
`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables/media/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I'm guessing one adds the jQuery javascript file you need to use jQuery.  One imports the jQueryUI(dependant on jQuery) js file so you are able to use the UI plugins.  The other one imports the dataTables(dependant on jQuery) so you can use the dataTables plugins

Answer (score 2):

Even these days (3 years later) this question is still actual. I did not use `theme_roller` as suggested.

In most cases problems are:

- wrong **ordering** styles or javascript files,
- **missed** to load any of required files,
- **conflict** or overwriting theme with extensions' style,
- extension **not initialized** (eg. `dom: "Bfltip"`).

To use jQueryUI theme with DataTables (in current version 1.10.8) next order ony worked for me:

**CSS**

1. `dataTables.jqueryui.css`
2. `smoothness/jquery-ui.css`

**JS**

1. `jquery.js`
2. `jquery-ui.js`
3. `jquery.dataTables.js`
4. `dataTables.jqueryui.js`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#dataContainer');
  table.DataTable({});
});
```

```css
@import url("//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/css/dataTables.jqueryui.css");
@import url("//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css");
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- link master.css -->
</head>

<body>
  <table id="dataContainer" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Position</th><th>Age</th><th>Start date</th></tr>
    </thead>

    <tr><td>batman</td><td>17</td><td>2015-12-26</td></tr>
    <tr><td>marko kraljevic</td><td>18</td><td>2015-12-26</td></tr>
    <tr><td>superman</td><td>1</td><td>2015-06-29</td></tr>
  </table>
  
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/dataTables.jqueryui.js"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

**Extensions**

Manual ([Download Builder](https://www.datatables.net/download/)) suggested to add extensions (eg. Buttons/Print,Select) styles at the end.

**CSS**

3. `buttons.jqueryui.css`

**JS**

5. `dataTables.buttons.js`
6. `buttons.jqueryui.js`
7. `buttons.print.js`

Although button works (don't forget to initialize it), but this **breaks** styling. Missing part to play with is (dataTables ver <  v1.11):

js

```
dom : '<"H"B<"dt-make-valign-center"lfr>>t<"F"ip>',
jQueryUI: true,
```

css

```
.dt-make-valign-center {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Working code with Button:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#dataContainer');
  table.DataTable({
    dom: '<"H"B<lfr>>t<"F"ip>',
    jQueryUI: true,
    buttons: [
      'print'
    ]
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/css/dataTables.jqueryui.css");
@import url("//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css");
@import url("//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.0/css/buttons.jqueryui.css");
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- link master.css -->
</head>

<body>
  <table id="dataContainer" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr>
      <td>batman</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>2015-12-26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>marko kraljevic</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>2015-12-26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>superman</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2015-06-29</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/dataTables.jqueryui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.0/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.0/js/buttons.jqueryui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.0/js/buttons.print.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```